# Setting a custom Content-Range Header using Restlet

Tags: java, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm using restlet 2.0.11 to provide data for a Dojo-based web application via a REST-Web-Interface.

According to the documentation of dojo, pagination is realized using the "content-range" header of HTTP, thus dojo expects a header like:

```
Content-Range: items 0-19/100
```

(Source: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/data/JsonRestStore.html)

Which means that the REST-Api provides the first 20 of 100 total items.

Setting the Content-Range header manually like this

```
getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers").add(new Parameter("Content-Range", "FooBar")
```

Results in the following error:

```
WARNING: Addition of the standard header "Content-Range" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
```

According to restlet's documentation the property is "message.entity.range" (Source: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/130-restlet.html)

The direct modification of this hash-map was also without success:

```
getResponse().getAttributes().put("message.entity.range", "FooBat");
```

Another way which seemed to be promising is using the "Representation"-object of restlet, since it has a setRange() method, but during request time, the object reference is null:

```
getResponse().getEntity()
```

So my question is: How to set a Content-Range header to a Restlet response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the equivalent Java properties in the Representation class, so this is getResponse().getEntity().setRange(myRange).

Comment: As I said in my question, getResponse().getEntity() is null. Is there a way to initialize it?

Comment: You need to set your response entity first, for example using the StringRepresentation class or any Representation subclass (see Javadocs)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it working. (by calling getResponse.setEntity(new StringRepresentation(...)). The next problem I have, is that the Content-Range is hard-coded to start with "bytes ". Dojo requires the header to start with "items ". I think I'm going to send a pull request to restlet with that feature included.

Comment: As a follow-up you contributed a nice enhancement here: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/pull/618