# Setting a custom Content-Range Header in Restlet for use in Dojo pagination fails

Tags: java, dojo, http-headers, restlet, http-content-range

After reading the following thread:

[Setting a custom Content-Range Header using Restlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263224/setting-a-custom-content-range-header-using-restlet)

I tried setting a custom unitname in the Range for the entity. This does not solve the Problem.

```
final Range range = new Range();
  range.setUnitName("items");
  range.setIndex(0);
  range.setSize(20);
```

[...]

```
getResponseEntity().setRange(range);
getResponseEntity().setSize(100);
```

The response now contains the following headers:

```
Content-Range:"items 0-19/100"
```

But Restlet also reads the range.size (20 in this case) and puts this as Content-Length automatically. Which results in:

```
Content-Length:"20"
```

This causes the client (e.g. Browser to stop reading after 20Bytes. (This also causes a null-pointer exception on the server, since the outputstream gets closed unexpectedly.)

The offical Restlet Documentation: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/http-headers-mapping

says Content-Length is available as message.entity.size, but this needs to be set to 100 to achieve the desired String in the Content-Range. This looks like a bug to me since range.size is used to calculate the content-length, not the entity size.

I can not set the Content-Length manually, since this is also a standard Header, and any manual changes to the standard headers are ingored.

The "Fix" proposed in the mentioned thread, only changes the Unitname - not the real unit - of the Range specified. It is still interpreted as bytes as is unusable as such.

Using the values in Range twice - for the content-range as well as the content-legth seems to be the problem.

**Is there any new way to manually override the headers , or make them dojo compatible?**

Manual changes are blocked in the HeaderUtils called by the ServerAdapter, causing the: "WARNING: Addition of the standard header [...] is not allowed..." warning.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reporting this. I've added an issue for that point: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1132 . I'll have a look later.

Comment: Hi, a fix has been developped, waiting for validation.

Comment: Hey!
Great, looks like it would fix the problem. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Having read the HTTP specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-4.1, it appears that Content-length contains the size of the payload that is to say the size of the range (in case of bytes range).

Answer (score 0):

support will be added in future 2.3.8 release of Restlet Framework.